# Why doesn't jQuery Tablesorter Plugin work on this Wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tablesorter

I have a working example of the Wordpress/jQuery plugin on this test page: http://beerlyrics.com/jimmy-jones/

I hardcoded it into the header on this page and both the pagination and filter mechanisms work correctly.

I have converted this over to a new page and am now using wp_enqueue to call all my scripts as it is supposed to be done:
http://farmball.com/boston/boston-red-sox/red-sox-roster/

Why wouldn't the pagination and filter mechanisms no longer work?

I have confirmed that it has nothing to do with a #baseball-table not defined error and an audiplayer error that comes up in Firebug. The #baseball-table error is occurs on both sites and I deactivated the plugin causing the audioplayer error and it made no difference to plugin performance.

Here is the code for js initialization:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#baseball-table").tablesorter({ debug: false, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'] })
                    .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false })
                    .tablesorterFilter({ filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                        filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                        filterColumns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                        filterCaseSensitive: false
                    });  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the issue -- Neither example is working for me at all in Chrome.  Though it is working in IE 8, it's throwing an error Webpage error details

Message: Function expected
Line: 15
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://beerlyrics.com/wp-content/themes/classic/tablesorter_filter.js

Comment: Yeah, Wordpress says to load js files in that manner but it broke the plugin altogether so I had to change that line back to function($). On the other site, I am able to load it if I hardcode into the header but I'm trying to figure out why it won't load using the "right" way (not hardcoding it but using wp_enqueue).

Comment: The developer moved the input box outside of the table which was breaking the parser in Chrome (and possibly Safari).

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.noConflict?](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict)

Comment: The jQuery library included with Wordpress loads in "no conflict" mode. In order to use the $ function as usual, use the following:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});

Unfortunately, doing this causes it to break altogether so I had to switch it back to function($) {

I feel I'm pretty close...

Answer (score 0):

I hired a developer to fix this. Strange but the fix was that there was a missing ( at the beginning of one of the js files in FTP though cPanel showed it at the beginning of the file. I use cPanel and didn't know it was missing.